# How to capture JS redirects in Selenium?

Tags: selenium

Is there any way to capture all the redirects on the page performed in JS? For instance, let's take a look at this web page making redirect using window.location

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Redirect JS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.location = "http://www.example.com";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

I would like to render web page and get all urls where user has been redirected. Is it possible? How to do that in selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html : webdriver has property **current_url**. After you driver.get() the page, I would assume current_url is the redirected URL. Is it not?

Comment: That's correct. I've already come across to this property. In fact it isn't saying whether it was redirect made by JS/Meta/HTTP, how many them were.

Comment: I am confused. Does current_url returns original URL (the one you get(), or the URL after redirect? And why you care how many and which kind of redirects happened? Only the resulting final URL should be important, IIUC. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Current_url return URL of the page after all the redirects. I am not using selenium for testing, instead I am creating a software for analyze web pages (SEO content), which have to detect some bad pratics. Redirect in JS is one of them.

Comment: Selenium is concerned about **cross-browser automation.** You need something sitting deeper in a particular browser. Using **specific calls deep into the browser.** Some Firefox/Chrome plugin, possibly enhanced for your needs.

Comment: Finally, I've switched to PhantomJS.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement "in Selenium" will make this impossible. Selenium interacts with a browser as a human would - a human should generally not know or care about all the redirects. If you are willing to abandon Selenium for this purpose, then there are libraries such as HttpBuilder (in the Java world) and many others (for other languages) that allow you to manipulate and watch HTTP traffic, which is what you are after here.